# Can't upload photo in MS database using PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server, image, sqlsrv

I have a problem uploading a photo in the database using PHP and Microsoft Server SQL. It's my first time and cant find the solution over the internet, can someone please help?

Here's my HTML code for the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>e-Scan Archiving - Accounting</title>
    <link href="main1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


  </head>

  <body>

    <form method="post" action="addMember.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
                  Please Enter the Members Name.
                </p>
                <p>
                  Name:
                </p>
                <input type="text" name="nameMember"/>

                <p>
                  Please Upload a Photo of yourself.
                </p>
                <p>
                  Photo:
                </p>
                <input type="hidden" name="size" value="6000000">
                <input type="file" name="photo"> 

                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" title="Add data to the Database" value="Add Name"/>
              </form>
      </body>
</html>
```

And here's my PHP code:

```
<?php

    include_once("NewConnectProcess.php");

    class UploadPicture extends Connection {
        public function doUploadData() {
            //This is the directory where images will be saved
            $target = "your directory";
            $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

            //This gets all the other information from the form
            $name=$_POST['nameMember'];
            $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

            //Writes the information to the database
            $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.pictureInfo (name,photo)
            VALUES ('$name','$pic')" ;

            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $sql);

            //Writes the photo to the server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
                {

                //Tells you if its all ok
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
                }
            else 
                {

                //Gives and error if its not
                echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
                }
            if( $stmt === false )
                {
                echo "Statement could not be executed.\n";
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                } 
            else 
                {
                echo "Rows affected: ".sqlsrv_rows_affected( $stmt )."\n<br>"; 
                }

            // Free statement and connection resources
            sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
            sqlsrv_close($this->conn);

        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
      $i = new UploadPicture();
      $i->connectDatabase();
      $i->doUploadData();
    }
?>
```

Here's my NewConnectProcess.php which is used for database connection, it works but I think it may help:

```
<?php

class Connection {

    public $conn;

    public function connectDatabase() {
        $serverName = "localhost"; 
        $uid = "sa";   
        $pwd = "joseph04";  
        $databaseName = "TestDatabase"; 

        $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>$databaseName); 

        // Connect using SQL Server Authentication 
        $this->conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  

        // Test Connection
        if( $this->conn === false )
        {
            echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Here's the error:
[image: error]

Comment: Did you check your table in db? It says that there is no 'photo' column in the error message.

Comment: I have a column in my database which it points, the column's name is picture with a data type of image, is that correct or should I change it to varchar?

Comment: The column name should be 'photo' instead of 'picture'.

Answer (score 0):

The error have indicated the problem. `uploadedfile` was not defined.

```
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). "
```

try changing it to ['photo'].

```
$_FILES['photo']['name']
```

Comment: the first error was gone when I did what you said but the second error still persist which is:
`The file dimensiondata.jpg has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directoryStatement could not be executed. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'photo'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'photo'. ) )`


What should I do? I don't know what to do, thanks in advance!

Comment: @JosephRojas this error means, there is no such column name called `photo` in `dbo.pictureInfo` table. You should check column names carefully and write **exact** name of column.